# ClickOnce Application Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I developed a C# winform application using Visual Studio 2013 (targeted .net 3.5 SP1). I published the application as ClickOnce. The application is installed on windows XP successfully, but when it tries to run immediately after installation, the following error occurs:

*object reference not set to an instance of an object*

I looked on the internet but still can not find a solution to this problem. I also asked this question [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6bef83b0-bbca-48b5-baa6-49f4dd3796ca/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object?forum=winformssetup), but didn't get answer yet.

**Edit:**

I don't get the error in debug mode (IDE). I get the error when I deploy the application so I don't know where in the code the error is issued. How can I know what the problem is? I also checked the windows Event Viewer and I suspect one of the errors I found in the Event Viewer. The description of the error in the Event Viewer is

> EventType clr20r3, P1 applaunch.exe, P2 2.0.50727.3053, P3 4889dc54,
>   P4 mscorlib, P5 2.0.0.0, P6 4889dc80, P7 4f2, P8 0, P9
>   system.security.security, P10 NIL.

Here is my program.cs file:

```
using SoftwareLocker;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyApplicationNamespace
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

            // Check if user is NOT admin
            if (!IsRunningAsAdministrator())
            {
                // Setting up start info of the new process of the same application
                ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);

                // Using operating shell and setting the ProcessStartInfo.Verb to “runas” will let it run as admin
                processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

                // Start the application as new process
                Process.Start(processStartInfo);

                // Shut down the current (old) process
                System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
                return;
            }

            Application.Run(new frmEnLogin());
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());
        }

        private static bool IsRunningAsAdministrator()
        {
            // Get current Windows user
            WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

            // Get current Windows user principal
            WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(windowsIdentity);

            // Return TRUE if user is in role "Administrator"
            return windowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: That's a classic problem and it appears when we try to use an object that has not be instantieted yet. In order to get a help you have to post here your code, in order to find where is the porblem exactly

Comment: Why no one answers me?